# Within RubyMine, selection of Ruby interpreter doesnt work - Windows 10

Tags: ruby, windows, sdk, rubymine

After selecting ruby.exe in the screen below, it loads for a while and then it fails and nothing happens.

[image: RubyMine settings]

Ruby installation was done succesfully I think because after doing ruby -v in cmd it gives this:

[image: ruby in cmd]

Error: [image: error in rubymine]

Comment: Is `Programma's` a valid / working directory name? The apostrophe seems a little odd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Stefan was correct. I had a directory name "Programma's". This was causing the problem. After renaming it "Programs", the problem was solved.